# Getting different Attribute values and Node values in XML tree using C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration-template name="TEMPLATE_NAME" version="v1.0">
    <configuration-item name="mx.reporting.setup.SqlTable" object-id="CM.353">
        <instances>
            <instance label="RTA_INSTANCE.REP,Client">
                <instance-key property="label" with-quotes="true">RTA_INSTANCE.REP</instance-key>
                <instance-key property="murex">0</instance-key>
            </instance>
        </instances>
    </configuration-item>
    <configuration-item name="mx.reporting.datamart.BatchOfFeeders" object-id="CM.418">
        <instances>
            <instance label="RBA_INSTANCE2">
                <instance-key property="label" with-quotes="true">RBA_INSTANCE2</instance-key>
            </instance>
        </instances>
    </configuration-item>
</configuration-template>
```

What I want is it to take out the configuration-template name ie TEMPLATE_NAME
and for each configuration Item list the object-id and Instance key

So in this case it would be

TEMPLATE_NAME CM.353 RTA_INSTANCE.REP
TEMPLATE_NAME CM.418 RBA_INSTANCE2

I manage to open the xml from a specified directory, and get some values

But don't know how to go through the XML properly

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO.Compression;

public class Sample
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //Create the XmlDocument.
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\TFS\SUP\System", "*.xml");
        string[] arr = new string[] {"Name1.xml", "Name2.xml"};

        Console.WriteLine(arr.Length);
        XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("configuration-item");
        XmlNodeList elemList2 = doc.GetElementsByTagName("instance-key");
        XmlNodeList elemList3 = doc.GetElementsByTagName("configuration-template");

        for (int b = 0; b < arr.Length; b++)
        {
            doc.Load(arr[b]);

            for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(elemList3[i].Attributes["name"].Value);
                Console.WriteLine(elemList2[i].InnerXml);
                Console.WriteLine(elemList[i].Attributes["object-id"].Value);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: First off, this is much easier with XDocument (not XmlDocument).

Comment: And similar questions have been asked many times already.

Comment: And just a hint: call GetElementsByTagName _after_ you load the docuemnt.

Comment: Thanks, the  doc.Load(arr[b]); was placed incorrectly in the code i pasted. Will read about XDocument

Comment: Make sure you always post the correct code.